# Can you remove PDF's after you add them to iBooks?

Tags: books, macos

I have iCould sync on. So all my books get sync across my devices. Great!

Now, my question is: can I remove the PDF's (from my Downloads folder) after I added them?

I tried it, it seems to work, but im not sure. Unlike with music you can right click on the book (in iBooks) and click `Show in Finder`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the books that you move to iBooks stored in

```
~/Library/Containers/com.apple.BKAgentService/Data/Documents/iBooks/
```

iBooks make a copy of every books that you move on it.

With iCloud Sync the Documents are stored in the following location - Thanks to @Rogier

```
~/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~apple~iBooks/Documents/
```

Personally I recommend that you make a backup or move your original ebooks on an external drive.

Comment: @date12 thanks, but not for me. I have iCloud sync on? I search  in the Library and found my PDF's in a different location  (?) "/Users/<username>/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~apple~iBooks/Documents/"

Answer (score 1):

I might maybe differ for certain version of OSX/macOS.

I'm using `macOS Sierra` and have iCloud **on** for iBooks.

The files are apparently copied (as dante12 said), but are stored in a different location, for me:

```
/Users/<your username>/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~apple~iBooks/Documents
```

Answer (score 0):

Open iBooks, then choose PDF's in the Navigation Panel at the left.
All pdf's are displayed on the right, CTL+click the book you want to delete, then choose "delete".